# How do I align these leftrightarrow in every columns?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, booktabs

How do I align these `leftrightarrow` in every columns? I'm going to put the `leftrightarrow` in every columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{SET 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{SET 2}} \\
    \cmidrule(rl){1-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-4}
     {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\
    \midrule
    $\mathrm{X_{A}}\leftrightarrow
    \mathrm{X_B}$ & B.1 & C.1 & D.1 \\
    $\mathrm{Y_{CD}} \leftrightarrow \mathrm{Y_N}$ & B.2 & C.2 & D.2\\
    $\mathrm{Z_{CDE}} \leftrightarrow \mathrm{Z_K}$  & B.3 & C.3& D.3  \\
     A.4 & B.4 & C.4 & D.4 \\
     A.5 & B.5 & C.5 & D.5  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

I want to apply that for all 4 columns.
So something like this.

[image]

This is my attemp to modify Simon Dispa code.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{SET 1}}    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{SET 2}} \\
        \cmidrule(rl){1-6} \cmidrule(rl){7-12}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{A long name}     & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A long name}   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A long name}   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A long name}     \\  %changed <<<<<<<<<<<
        \midrule
        $\mathrm{X_{A}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$     &  $\mathrm{X_{A}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$  &  $\mathrm{X_{A}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$ &  $\mathrm{X_{A}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$   \\
           $\mathrm{X_{BA}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$     &  $\mathrm{X_{BA}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$  &  $\mathrm{X_{BA}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$ &  $\mathrm{X_{BA}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$   \\
   
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: the subscripts are taking up more space - Z_CDE takes up max space causing misalignment - so simply use a `phantom{E}` with Y_CD - and a `phantom{DE}` with X_B for proper alignment

Comment: @jsbibra could you explain more? I don't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the arrows in its own column to align them and with the letter "A" (second table). `@{}` suppresses the intercolumn space.

[image: d]

```
 % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}        
    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{SET 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{SET 2}} \\
            \cmidrule(rl){1-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-4}
            {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\
            \midrule
            $\mathrm{X_{A}}\leftrightarrow
            \mathrm{X_B}$ & B.1 & C.1 & D.1 \\
            $\mathrm{Y_{CD}} \leftrightarrow \mathrm{Y_N}$ & B.2 & C.2 & D.2\\
            $\mathrm{Z_{CDE}} \leftrightarrow \mathrm{Z_K}$  & B.3 & C.3& D.3  \\
            A.4 & B.4 & C.4 & D.4 \\
            A.5 & B.5 & C.5 & D.5  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

The \verb|\leftrightarrow|  are now aligned:

    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{r@{}c@{}cccc}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{SET 1}}          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{SET 2}} \\
            \cmidrule(rl){1-4} \cmidrule(rl){5-6}
                                &A                  &                   & B  &  C   & D     \\
            \midrule
            $\mathrm{X_{A}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$     & B.1 & C.1 & D.1   \\
            $\mathrm{Y_{CD}}$   &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{Y_N}$     & B.2 & C.2 & D.2   \\
            $\mathrm{Z_{CDE}}$  &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{Z_K}$     & B.3 & C.3 & D.3   \\
                                &A.4                &                   & B.4 & C.4 & D.4   \\
                                &A.5                &                   & B.5 & C.5 & D.5   \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow up question.

[image: f]

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r@{}c@{}cccc}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{SET 1}}          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{SET 2}} \\
        \cmidrule(rl){1-4} \cmidrule(rl){5-6}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{A long name}                             & B   & C   & D     \\  %changed <<<<<<<<<<<
        \midrule
        $\mathrm{X_{A}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$     & B.1 & C.1 & D.1   \\
        $\mathrm{Y_{CD}}$   &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{Y_N}$     & B.2 & C.2 & D.2   \\
        $\mathrm{Z_{CDE}}$  &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{Z_K}$     & B.3 & C.3 & D.3   \\
                            &A.4                &                   & B.4 & C.4 & D.4   \\
                            &A.5                &                   & B.5 & C.5 & D.5   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

**SECOND UPDATE** more  `\leftrightarrow` (s)

What you call a "column" is actually three tabular columns, the middle column of which contains the `\leftrightarrow`. The table now has 4*3= twelve columns.

[image: x]

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ r@{}c@{}l    r@{}c@{}l    r@{}c@{}l    r@{}c@{}l }     % 12 columns    
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{SET 1}} &\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{SET 2} }  \\
    \cmidrule(rl){1-6} \cmidrule(rl){7-12}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{A long name} &   &B& &   &C& &\multicolumn{3}{c}{A longer name}  \\  %changed <<<<<<<<<<<
    \midrule
    $\mathrm{X_{A}}$    &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$     & $\mathrm{X_{A}}$  &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$ & $\mathrm{X_{A}}$  &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$ & $\mathrm{X_{A}}$  &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{X_B}$ \\
    $\mathrm{Y_{CD}}$   &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{Y_N}$     & $\mathrm{Y_{CD}}$ &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{Y_N}$ & $\mathrm{Y_{CD}}$ &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{Y_N}$ & $\mathrm{Y_{CD}}$ &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{Y_N}$ \\
    $\mathrm{Z_{CDE}}$  &$\leftrightarrow$  &$\mathrm{Z_K}$     &&&  &&& &&&    \\
                                    &A.4&   &   &&  &   & & &&  \\
                                    &A.5&   &   &&  &   & & &&  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thanks, if I replace the header name `A` by `\text{a long name}` then I get the problem that spacing around the left and right arrow too much like in the link below. 
https://ibb.co/5sk0j4c

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @emnha Please see the updated answer.

Comment: How to apply this for every column? I have been trying to copy and paste but not succeed.

Comment: I added 12 columns but stuck with this `\begin{tabular}{r@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}`

Comment: @emnha I am sorry but I do not understand your new goal. Please add your new code to your question or better still post a new one.

Comment: Now we have 4 columns but only the first column has `\leftrightarrow` but I want to add that for all 4 columns.

Comment: I have just updated my post with one image showing the desired output. Sorry that I should have added that in my  original post instead of just saying words.

Comment: @emnha Please see the updated answer. What you call a "column" is actually three tabular columns. The table now has 4*3= twelve columns.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**
Considering your comment, the letter A should be in the middle of the first two column. So the second table row should be

```
    \SetCell[c=2]{c} A
        &   & B & C & D                       \\
```

or in the case of longer name

```
    \SetCell[c=2]{c} \text{a long name}
        &   & B & C & D                       \\
```

This change is now done in MWE below.

Since you load `tabularray` in document preamble, I would use it in writing table. Code is simpler and more clear (to my opinion, of course):

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[r, mode=math, rightsep=-5pt] Q[l, mode=math] cc},
             %row{1,2}= {mode=text, font=\bfseries}
             }
        \toprule
    \SetCell[c=3]{c} SET 1
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} SET 2      
                    &                           \\
    \SetCell[c=2]{c} \text{a long name}
        &   & B & C & D                       \\
        \midrule
    \mathrm{X_{A}}      & \leftrightarrow \mathrm{X_B}  & B.1 & C.1 & D.1   \\
    \mathrm{Y_{CD}}     & \leftrightarrow \mathrm{Y_N}  & B.2 & C.2 & D.2   \\
    \mathrm{Z_{CDE}}    & \leftrightarrow \mathrm{Z_K}  & B.3 & C.3 & D.3   \\
    \SetCell[c=2]{c}    A.4
        &   &   B.4 & C.4 & D.4   \\
    \SetCell[c=2]{c}    A.5
        &   &   B.5 & C.5 & D.5   \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As can be seen from above MWE, math expression are divided between two columns, first has right aligned contents and the second left. space between two column is reduced for 5pt (what is equal to `\tabcolsep-1pt`).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks good but if I replace `A` by `\text{A long name}` then there is a misalignment between the name and the content in the column like in the link below. 
https://ibb.co/J5MBjkK

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @emnha, is this cell content wider than sum of width of first two columns? If this is not a case, than  you should show, what you doing. The best in the new question ...

Comment: I don't think so. I showed it with the image in my comment above.

Comment: @emnha, see edited answer.